# How to reset Bounding Box without effecting the object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, 3d-view, edit-mode

I got a problem with an upright object which with tilt bounding box.

Because its bounding box is tilt , I can't symmetric sculpt properly.

Although I can use mirror modify to get symmetric effect, still wondering is there a way to reset the bounding box without effecting the object inside?

### [image]

This is the object I made.

### [image: 1]

Its bounding box is tilt.
[image]

Comment: File uploading has been completed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object has been scaled and rotated in object mode but the rotation has not been applied.

In object mode press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply transformations.

[image]

read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)